# DB design for appointment scheduler

Tags: django, database, web-applications, calendar

I want to build a web-based appointment scheduler. Currently I am using Django but I think it's a general question. Say there are teachers and students. And there is a calendar with a bunch of 1 hour time slots. Each teacher can designate which time slots they are available. And students can book teachers time slots.

On the view side, a student can first select a teacher, then a full calendar for that teacher is shown with their availability, just like Calendly.

For teachers and students, I feel I can have one user table and have one column indicating whether a user is a teacher or a student.

The question is how should I design a table for appointments. The idea I currently have is to create a table where each row is a single time slot which has starting time and date, a teacher id, and optionally a student id. If student id is null, that means that time slot of the teacher is available.

Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like a good design. Don't forget to declare a `unique together` constraint to avoid dups. Also, on TimeSlot, the student should be nullable to allow students to join a free timeSlot. Here it is:

- **Teacher**:

  - id (pk)
  - name, ...
- **Student**:

  - id (pk)
  - name, ...
- **TimeSlot**:

  - id (pk)
  - teacher_id (not null, fk to teacher)
  - student_id (nullable *#!Important* , fk to student)
  - date (nut null)
  - starting_hour (nut null)
  - **Constraint unique together** *#!Important*: teacher_id, date, starting_hour.

On django you can declare it as many-to-many [relationships with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

```py
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slots = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='TimeSlot')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        blank = True,  #!Important
        null =True,    #!Important
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    starting_hour = models.IntegerField(max_length=64)

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint( #!Important
            fields=['teacher', 'date', 'starting_hour'],
            name='unique one teacher by slot')
    ]
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but why do we need to have     <pre>slots = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='TimeSlot')<code>

Comment: It's just a suggestion. Also work without it. Read linked docs.

Comment: If I use one table for both student and teacher, say User, and have 'type' field in the table indicating if a user is student or teacher, TimeSlot student and teacher fields both have User as a foreignKey. Then how can I put a constrain that student.type == STUDENT and teacher.type == TEACHER? It seems that model.Q only works for the fields in the current table. Or is it better to have separate tables for student and teacher?

Comment: Not a good idea because student and teacher don't have the same relations. But you can inherit both tables from User table.